# How can I rescale dataframe so each row have magnitude of 1 in R?

Tags: r, vector, scale, rescale

This is sample of my matrix and my code. I want to rescale my dataframe so that the each row has magnitude 1.
I'm new to r and in the tutorial the instructor said "divide each element of a row by the magnitude of the row." however I'm not sure how can I get the magnitude of the row or rescale the dataframe. So I tried to use **apply()** however after testing my rescale using **sqrt(sum(sc_mydata[r,]^2))** I didn't get 1 and I the result of x should be 1

```
#dataframe
myData <- myData[1:12]

#transpose
x <- t(myData)

#rescale the data
sc_mydata = apply(x[-1,], 1, scale)

#test rescale 
for (r in 1:nrow(sc_mydata)) {
  #test rescale if this  is equal to 1 then the rescaling worked 
  x <- sqrt(sum(sc_mydata[r,]^2))
  
  }
```

Comment: Please add some reproducible code, we don't know how `myData` looks like.

Answer (score 2):

If by "the magnitude of the row" your instructor means "the sum of the row", this works:

```
sc_mydata <- apply(x, 1, function(x) x / sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))
sc_mydata <- t(sc_mydata)
```

For some reason, the row-wise `apply()` function transposes the data frame, so I had to transpose it back. I don't use apply much (prefer the `tidyverse` tools to base R) so idk why that happens.

Comment: The sample data suggests `NA` values, you might need `sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)`.

Comment: @AdamB. thank you for your help I think it's working  can I ask how can I confirm if the rescale work I tried to apply sqrt(sum(sc_mydata[r,]^2)) but it didn't give me 1 for each row

Answer (score 1):

We could do this in a vectorized way with `rowSums`

```
x/rowSums(x)
```